# Rails test throwing Deprecation Warning over attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, attr-encrypted

Rails test is throwing a deprecation warning over a gem (attr_encrypted) which is already updated to the latest version. It reads:

`DEPRECATION WARNING: <custom_attribute_name> is not an attribute known` `to Active Record. This behavior is deprecated and will be removed in` 
`the next version of Rails. If you'd like <custom_attribute_name> to be` `managed by Active Record, add attribute :<custom_attribute_name> to` `your class.`

Not sure what it is asking me to do... it must be declared using attr_encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecation warning is something the attr_encrypted gem needs to fix, but it seems there is a workaround by adding the attribute call as mentioned in the warning.

See https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/issues/260